# How to organise JSON data to return multiple values

Tags: javascript, json

I am building a simple tool where people can input their postcode to see if they have a windfarm in their area. The data has been organised by a named location, and because of the specific API mapping tool I use I would want to preserve that. An example of the data would be:

| Location | Windfarm name |
| --- | --- |
| Copeland | Sustainable Keswick |
| Crewe and Nantwich | Nantwich Hydro |
| Derbyshire Dales | Matlock Community Energy Project |
| Derbyshire Dales | Derby Dales Community Energy |

I've made a similar tool before where I used keyed json, but the issue was the type I have made before there was only ever one value per location, as in:

```
"Copeland": {
      "hasWindfarm": "Yes",
}
```

This time for each location, I want to return the name (and perhaps other data) about each individual windfarm. But my usual set up is getting stumped by the fact there's multiple locations with multiple windfarms.

My question is about how best to arrange and fetch the JSON data. I'm only a really basic JSON and Javascript user, so I'm not sure what is the most efficient way of arranging and fetching the data

Comment: what's the input and the desired output?

Comment: Before worrying about the syntax of the JSON or object structure, first semantically describe your data.  What is that description?  Do you want a *collection* (array) of *locations* (objects), each of which has a *name* (string) and a *windfarm name* (string)?  Or something else?

Comment: How about a simple `"location1": [ "wfname1", "wfname2" ]` approach. You can easily retrieve the list of windfarm names for a given location and you can tell that a given location has 1+ windfarms from the `length > 0` of the list of windfarms associated with that location.

Comment: @David So the hope would be that a person inputs their postcode, the postcode returns the location "Derbyshire Dales" (all the way up to there I can do), and then I can match that location to my JSON so it returns: "In Derbyshire Dales, there are two windfarms: Derby Dales Community Energy and Matlock Community Energy Project".

Comment: @GeorgiaO'Brien: What exactly prevents you from doing this?  When you make an attempt, what specifically doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 2):

You could try putting an array of all the windfarms in a certain area, for example

```
{"Copeland": {  
   "windfarms": ["windfarm1", "windfarm2", "windfarm3"]
}}
```

To access the windfarms in a certain area, you could do something like:

```
const windfarmData = `{"Copeland": {"windfarms": ["windfarm1","windfarm2","windfarm3"]}}`;

// Parse JSON data
const parsedData = JSON.parse(windfarmData);

// For each windfarm in Copeland, print out their names

for (var i=0; i < parsedData.Copeland.windfarms.length; i++) {
   console.log(parsedData.Copeland.windfarms[i]);
}
```

This will print out each of the windfarms in a certain area.

Alternatively, if you wanted to list more information about each windfarm, your JSON could be formatted like this:

```
const windfarmData = {"Copeland": {
   "windfarm1": {
       "employees": 300
   },
   "windfarm2": {
       "employees": 500
   },
   "windfarm3": {
       "employees": 100
   }
}}
```

Then, assuming you've already parsed the JSON, you can access the data like so: `parsedData.Copeland.windfarm1.employees`.
This should return: `300`.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please accept this answer, per stackoverflow guidelines